# MS Access SQL - How to pull last 13 months data from the first of the first month?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I tried the below code to pull last 13 months of data. But it is not pulling from the 1st of the month. How can I modify it to pull data from the first day of the month?
For e.g. If I am running it today (11/13/18), I want data from 11/1/17 to today.

```
    SELECT * FROM MyTable T 
    WHERE T.[Date Joined] >= DATEADD("m", -13, DATE());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the day to 1 as

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable T 
WHERE T.[Date Joined] >= DATEADD("d", -(DAY(Date())-1),DATEADD("m", -13, DATE());
```

Or by using **[`DATESERIAL()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503)** function which return a `DATE` from parts as

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable T 
WHERE T.[Date Joined] >= DATEADD("m", -13, DATESERIAL(YEAR(Date()), MONTH(DATE()), 1))
```

It will get the `YEAR` part from the date which is `2018` in your case, then get the `MONTH` part which is 11 and `1` which is the day and concatenate them to return a `DATE` as `2018-11-1`

Comment: Oh yeah that's what you think

Comment: Thank you @Sami. I used Dateseriel function.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable T 
    WHERE T.[Date Joined] >= DATEADD("m", -13, Dateserial(year(date()), month(date()),1));
```

uses

```
Dateserial(year(date()), month(date()),1)
```

which gives you the 1st of the current month  
so you subtract from this the 13 months.